# Distinction of usage between identifier-name & non-restrictive NP

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

**Context:** Primary school teacher and local Shildon Town Councillor, Kelly Ambrosini, investigates the decisions that have led to Sunnydale school reaching the precipice of closure.

*Kelly Ambrosini - is a supplementary (non-restrictive) appositive. The appositive is a definite NP, so a determiner is not required.**

Would this example here be non-restrictive appositive following: suspected gunman?

What defines definite NP and how does it differ from the usage explained in the nytimes source? Just the assumption that their is only one primary teacher/councillor or that the description preceding the name  is reasonably sufficient to say the name is non-restrictive?

**Example**: Suspected gunman Kyle Rittenhouse was arrested and charged with murdering two BLM protesters.
https://archive.nytimes.com/query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage-9E06E6D9163EF934A15756C0A9649D8B63.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is incorrectly set off by commas. It should be:

> Primary school teacher and local Shildon Town Councillor Kelly Ambrosini investigates...

It is restrictive, since many people are primary school teachers, and at least a few are Shildon Town Councillors. Thus, the meaning of the preceding descriptors must be restricted by the name of the individual.

The second example,

> Suspected gunman Kyle Rittenhouse was...

is correctly punctuated, and is also restrictive, since many people may be suspected gunmen.

Both of these appositive phrases are example of "false titles", as described here:
[Wikipedia "false title"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title)

> A false, coined, fake, bogus or pseudo-title, also called a Time-style adjective and an anarthrous nominal premodifier, is a kind of appositive phrase before a noun. It is said to formally resemble a title, in that **it does not start with an article**, but is a common noun phrase, not a title. An example is the phrase convicted bomber in "convicted bomber Timothy McVeigh".

This "false title" usage is contrasted with one that starts with the name of the individual:

> Kyle Rittenhouse, the suspected gunman, was ...

In that example, the descriptor "the suspected gunman", is not restrictive because it's less specific than the person's name, so it has an article and is set off by commas.

(The "false title" usage described in the Wikipedia article is so named by analogy with a real title, such as King Richard III, or President Obama, which would not be preceded by articles.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the phrase "false title", so thanks. I note that it is particularly prevalent in journalism, and almost absent in speech.

Comment: @ColinFine It was new to me too, linked from the Wikipedia article "apposiition".

Comment: He unfortunately ran into a [suspected gunman], Kyle Rittenhouse.   If it is written like this, then the title just becomes a np in apposition, right.

Comment: That mixes up a couple of things (the article "a", the brackets, and the comma). I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase, does apposition only occur when the noun is the direct object of something else, such as :He shot a suspected gunman, Kyle.  Versus suspected gunman Kyle Rittenhouse, or do we still class them as in apposition or false titles as you say.

Comment: A compound noun with two nouns in apposition can be a subject or an object,. "Gunman Kyle Rittenhouse shot two people." "The police arrested gunman Kyle R."